# android get multiple contacts by phone numbers

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I have a list of contact numbers and would like to get contact records of all the contacts that match the phone numbers. i have only seen queries for finding a single contact based on a single phone number search using PhoneLookup. Thanks in advance